# how to add re-order to wp user panel of wordpress?

Tags: php

i am trying to add re-order for user panel in wordpress. I tried to intall some plugin called post re-order but did not work out for user panel. plz suggest me with the best idea.

thx
[image]
screenshot of wp backend panel

Comment: You'd have to use [`add_submenu_page( 'users.php' ...`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) to add a 'Reorder' page under the users menu. However, unless you are using some kind of meta key to order them on, they don't have a `menu_order` property like pages so you would have to write extensive logic yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can re order admin left menu by below code:

```
/*
 * Code below groups Dashboard/Posts/Pages/Comments together at the top of the dashboard menu.
 * If you were to have a custom type that you want to add to the group use the following edit.php?post_type=YOURPOSTTYPENAME
 */
function reorder_my_admin_menu( $__return_true ) {
    return array(
         'index.php', // Dashboard
         'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages 
         'edit.php', // Posts
         'upload.php', // Media
         'themes.php', // Appearance
         'separator1', // --Space--
         'edit-comments.php', // Comments 
         'users.php', // Users
         'separator2', // --Space--
         'plugins.php', // Plugins
         'tools.php', // Tools
         'options-general.php', // Settings
   );
}
add_filter( 'custom_menu_order', 'reorder_my_admin_menu' );
add_filter( 'menu_order', 'reorder_my_admin_menu' );
```

Above code used [custom_menu_order](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/custom_menu_order) and [menu_order](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/menu_order) hook to re order existing menu items. Hope this help you well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Admin Menu order plugin. There are several, [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) is one of them.

Also, those are not "posts", they are backend panel menu items.